# OpenShift Origin single master multiple nodes

Tags: openshift-origin

With OpenShift Origin in a single master - 2 node installation do you need to have Docker running on the master and configured with Docker storage (Docker storage pool) as you do on the nodes? This is not clear to me though installation indicates all OpenShift servers require Docker? Not sure why the master would? Thank you.

Comment: Are you using the Ansible install method or trying to set things up manually? If use Ansible install method it should worry about such details.

Comment: Hi Graham, I amusing Ansible. Yes I thought it might. But with Docker enabled and running on master during install a fail occurs during health check. "One or more checks failed Details:  check "docker_storage":
Use of loopback devices with the Docker devicemapper storage driver
(the default storage configuration) is unsupported in production.
Please use docker-storage-setup to configure a backing storage volume." I did not configure docker storage on the master. I did not run docker storage setup on the master. I did not anticipate using docker storage on the master.

Comment: Are you saying you already had Docker running on the target machine? The idea as I understand it is that you start with bare machines and let Ansible provision what it needs in the way it wants. If you put stuff on machines in advance it is more likely to confuse Ansible scripts.